# Gravity Forms Hide/disable entry creation

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to disable the entry creation for a gravity form I have on my WordPress website. The form consists of username/password for another application (not WordPress) and I do not want it to list/create entries in the WordPress database every time this form is used.  I have a dashboard widget also which displays all forms in the website as well as all the entries of each. I am trying to find a way to either hide the form entirely from the widget or not create entries at all.

I tried the following hook,thinking it would stop creating entries.

```
    add_filter("gform_disable_post_creation", "disable_post_creation", 10, 3);
       function disable_post_creation($is_disabled, $form, $entry){
       return true;
    }
```

But this isn't working. Does anyone know of a way I can hide the form or disable entry creation for this specific form?

Answer (score 3):

While you can’t currently prevent Gravity Forms from creating an entry, you **can** get the same desired outcome by *automatically deleting the entry after the form has finished submitting* using the `gform_after_submission_{$form['id']}` action hook and the Gravity Forms API.

Here's a full tutorial on how to do it manually (disclaimer: I wrote it):

https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/prevent-gravity-forms-entry-creation/

That tutorial also has a link to the plugin I wrote that allows you to simply check a box on the Form Settings page to prevent entry creation and everything is handled for you.

Comment: Well I tried both the code as well as the plugin. I keep getting an error class GFAPI: not Found. According to the documentation, GFAPI is available in the path /plugins/gravityforms/includes/api.php but in my folder there is no api.php and I'm not able to load the class. I tried searching too but apart from the API documentation this issue is not discusses. I must be missing out on something crucial. Can you please assist me further? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to be using the latest version of Gravity Forms